# want to make these php function work inside this html echo

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

this is php document, when building this form i want to use that forech function to build the dropdown menu... as im inside the (HTML) it doesnt work... anyone has a clue how to make it work?

```
echo <<<HTML
    <form method="post" class="form">
    <label for="datafalta">Data da falta</label>
    <input id="datafalta" type="date" value="{$dateToday}"  name="datafalta"/>
    <label for="alunofalta">Selecionar aluno</label>
    <select name="aluno">
         <option value="0" selected></option>
        foreach ($calfaltas as $a) {
            <option value="1">$a->nome</option>
        }

    </select><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
    </form>
HTML;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot mix html and php as you are. For a start you are missing such simple parts like `''` around strings.

```
<?php
echo ' 
<html>
    <form method="post" class="form">
        <label for="datafalta">Data da falta</label>
        <input id="datafalta" type="date" value="' . $dateToday . '"  name="datafalta"/>
        <label for="alunofalta">Selecionar aluno</label>
        <select name="aluno">
            <option value="0" selected></option>';

            foreach ($calfaltas as $a) {
                echo '
                <option value="1">' . $a->nome . '</option>';
            }

        echo '
        </select><br /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
    </form>
<html>';
```

Comment: OP is using herdoc syntax that doesn't require quoted strings. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for that info, never knew this event existed :).

Comment: Worked like a charm... 1 question... why use <html> instead of <<<HTML?

Comment: @VincentAdams as charlietfl stated (which i was unaware about), that format of `<<<` is called herdoc. I've personally never seen it before and `<html>` is just the standard `<html>` opening tag. I guess choose your style and follow it through. If you want to keep the herdoc style then either answer by charlietfl or Jose are good.

Comment: ohhh... tnhx... anyway it worked perfectly... tnhx for the help everyone :D

Comment: @VincentAdams Glad it works for you either way :)

Comment: @VincentAdams, you may click the checkmark of this answer to accept it. Reward people for their effort.

Comment: ohhh... just saw it :D 1st time asking something so didnt knew about that... tnhx :D

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
    <?php
    echo"<form method='post' class='form'>
        <label for='datafalta'>Data da falta</label>
        <input id='datafalta' type='date' value='{$dateToday}'  name='datafalta'/>
        <label for='alunofalta'>Selecionar aluno</label>
        <select name='aluno'>
             <option value='0' selected></option>
";
            foreach ($calfaltas as $a) {
               echo " <option value='1'>$a->nome</option>";
            }
    echo"
        </select><br /><br />
        <input type='submit' name='enviar' value='Enviar'>
        </form>";
    ?>
```

Comment: This wont work. You are using `"` for the starting of strings but hes also using `"` for his values etc inside his html tags. You need to use `'` to start an echo string.

Comment: Thanks @Matt. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Updated. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Break your heredoc in two parts with the foreach in the middle :

```
<?php
echo <<<HTML
    <form method="post" class="form">
    <label for="datafalta">Data da falta</label>
    <input id="datafalta" type="date" value="{$dateToday}"  name="datafalta"/>
    <label for="alunofalta">Selecionar aluno</label>
    <select name="aluno">
         <option value="0" selected></option>
HTML;
        foreach ($calfaltas as $a) {
            echo "<option value='{$a->id}'>{$a->nome}</option>";
        }
echo <<<HTML
    </select><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
    </form>
HTML;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the `foreach` loop inside the heredoc output....create all the options in variable and output that variable in the middle of the string

```
 $options='';
 foreach ($calfaltas as $a) {
      $options.='<option value="'.$a->someProperty.'">'.$a->nome.'</option>';
 }

echo <<<HTML
    <form method="post" class="form">
    <label for="datafalta">Data da falta</label>
    <input id="datafalta" type="date" value="{$dateToday}"  name="datafalta"/>
    <label for="alunofalta">Selecionar aluno</label>
    <select name="aluno">
         <option value="0" selected></option>
         $options

    </select><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
    </form>
HTML;
```

note you need to fix value of the `<option>` tag to reflect proper data in array

Comment: tnhx for noticing... allmost forgot that. using it as <option value="$a->id">' . $a->nome . '</option>';